# How can I access Google search results programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

I am using the Google Custom Search in my web page and want to filter the results before displaying the results.  I cannot find any callback in Google's documenation where I can access the results so I can tweek them before displaying the results.   Below is my code in my web page.

```
      <script>
 (function() {
  var cx = '99999999999999999999:ddddddddd';
  var gcse = document.createElement('script');
  gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
  gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<div style="font-size: 1.3em">
    <gcse:searchbox gname="search"></gcse:searchbox>

    <gcse:searchresults gname="search"></gcse:searchresults>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can access the results before they are displayed in the searchresults element?

Comment: There is a callback, it might be what you're looking for. Check this [section](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element?hl=en#tagparams) of the docs

Comment: I saw that example but it doesn't really show the json parsing logic

Answer (score 0):

Custom Search [has an API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) which allows you to retrieve the results in JSON or XML format. You'll probably want to use the [official JavaScript client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) library to access the API more conveniently.

Comment: I saw the javascript api but it requires a google api key which I didn't really want to do but maybe I have no other choice.